# Ворд или Вёрд?

Tags: фонетика

Чаще пишут "Ворд", хотя по-английски ведь произносится куда ближе к Ё. И как правильнее писать: так, как принято, или как ближе к оригинальному звучанию?

Comment: Потому что мы записываем это слово максимально близко к исходному написанию, а не звучанию, ИМХО. К тому же весьма сомнительно, что в английском слове Word слышится звук ё.

Answer (score 5):

Не вижу причин для замены сложившегося написания. 
По-русски "Вёрд" никто не говорит, да и не в этом дело. 
Такие вещи лучше всего не транскрибировать, а транслитерировать - т.е. передавать средствами заимствующего языка не звуки, но **знаки** языка-источника. 
Ко всему прочему утверждение о том, что в английском этот звук ближе к Ё весьма спорно.
Ё в русском - это два звука. А если один, то равный О (с точностью до несущественных призвуков).

Comment: > А если один, то равный О (с точностью до несущественных призвуков).
Т.е. Шрёдингер = Шродингер? Сомнительно.

Comment: При чем тут котовладелец?!
Но если о нем, то вопрос спорный. 
Шрёдингер плохо тем, что смягчает Р. А звука "О умляут" в русском просто нет. Есть некий аллофон звука O, чуточку более близкий к немецкому OE, чем чистое O. 
А хорош Шр**ё**дингер тем, что ближе к немецкому **написанию**.  
Но к Ворду/Вёрду это не имеет отношения. 
Во-первых, это английская фонетика, не немецкая, во-вторых, это название, вполне ассимилированное русским.
"По-англицки" было бы вообще что-то типа "У(oeр)Д". В скобках - единый звук.

Answer (score 1):

программисты говорят - "ВЁРД", обыватели- "ВОРД")))

Comment: Вы точно знаете, что они - программисты?
Лет за пятнадцать-двадцать ничего подобного не слыхивал...
Хотя я от своего брата чего только не слыхивал, но обычно это максимум единичные случаи...

Answer (score 1):

Я - программист. Я говорю и пишу "ворд". Мои коллеги - тоже. Пользователи - как попало.

Answer (score 0):

Говорите и пишите **Word**. Можно произносить с каким угодно акцентом, Вас поймут, зато не нужно морочить голову русским написанием иностранных слов. По ТВ и когда бываем за границей видим и слышим как говорят по-английски немцы, поляки, французы, японцы, индийцы - мало  кто блещет оксфордским произношением, как правило, тарахтят как попадя.